# Div under a full screen div with "fixed or absolute"?

Tags: html, css, web

I've been looking into mimicking some websites to learn some new neat techniques.

And while doing so, I came up with some trouble emulating a certain site.

http://dangblast.com/ heres the link to the site.

If you look at the top of the website there is a div that contains a background image that has an "absolute" position and a "background-size" that covers and my question starts here.

Right underneath that div, there is another div (id = "about") that follows up right after and surprisingly the div always comes right after even if the window size is changed.

From my understating, I thought that it was impossible to stack an "abosolute" or "fixed" positioned div right after another, they just become layered.

Is there a trick to achieving this type of effect?

right now I have a div in my website that looks like the following

The Html

```
<div id = "fill_screen">
</div>

<div id = "followup_div">
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#fill_screen {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

#followup_div {
background-color: yellow;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Is there a way to make divs fit right under a absolute or fixed positioned div that is also filling up the window of the screen? That is dynamic to the web-browser size?

I did some research and there were techniques using viewports height (vh), but I saw that some old browsers were not compatible with it.

Comment: Ever heard of a `z-index:`?

Comment: @PHPglue: Yes, but isnt that usually used to decide the order of the layering ? like what goes on top and what goes on bottom

Comment: I guess I didn't know what you meant by `"under"`. If those `fixed` or `absolute` positioned Elements have children then under those children it is possible. If a `position:fixed;` Element is relative to the another Element that takes up the entire screen then `100%` wouldn't leave room, of course.

Comment: @PHPglue: Yeah, I was scared that viewers with more coding knowledge would have a hard time understanding my question. But I guess if I were to make the question more simple. I have a DIV element that needs to fill the entire screen until the user scrolls and reveals another div right under the first DIV element that is filling the entire screen.

Comment: @PHPglue: Could you give me an example of how would that look like ? Im still pretty new at JavaScript.

Comment: Misunderstood the question.

Comment: @PHPglue: Nah haha it was my fault for not explaining it more clearly ! Thanks for the help though !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify the position of the followup_div. The followup_div uses absolute positioning and has to be moved 100% from the top.

HTML:

```
<div id = "fill_screen">
    <button>text</button>
</div>

<div id = "followup_div">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
margin:0px;
}

#fill_screen {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
background-color:red;
}

#followup_div {
background-color: yellow;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkf7guzu/)**

Comment: YES ! That was exactly what I was looking for thank you so much ! I have another small question though. If I were to add more followup_div's underneath, would the css "top" value have to increase more ?

Comment: You would just have to modify the top position for each new div added. You should take a look at Parallax web design because that is what this is.

Comment: Gotcha ! I'll defiantly look into that. Wish I could give you a billion upvotes but that would have to wait untill my reputation goes up !

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the top of id="intro" you can see class="intro-down". this anchor makes space for fixed div and if you remove it you can see that id "intro"(which is a fixed div) will be disappeared.